# Remote desktop connection

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-connection

Is it possible to establish a remote desktop connection to a computer and then have the computer running, and performing the tasks it was set up to do without having an active computer connected to it?

When I set my home computer to sleep, the server seems to not perform the actions I want it to, but to stop.

Maybe there is something I'm doing wrong?

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: I'm running a browser based plugin, which stops functioning if I set my home computer to sleep or if I shut it off.

Comment: if it is a sleep issue, I know what I would do, create a new power profile, that will either not sleep , nor disk standby, or delay those things for a much longer time.  Put it in a shorcut >powercfg -s 7c79aead-8184-4fba-bef5-5439edfec4f0  The big number being how the system recognises the power profile , you have to discover that for yourself. Then run that shortcut to change the power settings before you disconnect from it.    later on Change back to an approprite power profile for normal operation.   I actually use 4 toggle batches, that give me 8 profiles to change that quickly

Comment: I'll definately try that! I'll be back with an answer when I've tested it.

Comment: On the RDP server I'm renting I don't have permission to edit power options apparently. I'm guessing that shortcut won't work then?

Comment: If it can help... I'm running an imacros script and everytime I set my home computer to sleep / shut it off it seems firefox doesn't respond and continue to do the tasks, but the imacros seems to be going on I think. Maybe this is site specific.

Comment: I wondered about that, in your question it does not define if your home computer was the server , or if your in charge of the server itself. A server your not in charge of , you would have to do something on it (i dont know) that would keep it from sleep, or ask the people in charge of it to change it somehow.  Your question could be longer with way more information/explaination in it, so more things are understood about your situation.

Comment: It seems to run more smoothly when I switched over to google chrome instead of firefox. It doesn't seem to pause anymore now.  I really appreciate all the help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Whether RDP allows you to disconnect and reattach or whether it simply terminates the session is configurable.  But that may not be under your control, since it is a feature commonly set in group policies for both performance and security of a network.

Here are a few links discussing the topic:

- *[Disconnecting From Remote Desktop Session While Running Automated Tests](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/56552/)*
- *[GPO to kill disconnected and idle RDP connections](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/377db424-e0aa-42b9-968d-876be03e8f38/gpo-to-kill-disconnected-and-idle-rdp-connections)*
- *[Configure Timeout and Reconnection Settings for Remote Desktop Services Sessions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx)*